# How to avoid a square to make an other one disappear an take his color when I animate in HTML5 inside a canvas tag?

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I begin to animate a blue square in HTML5 inside a canvas tag, I add another red square as enemy; but when I move the blue square, the red one disappear and the blue one turn red. In fact, I want to keep the color of the blue square and I don't want the red one disappear, how can I solve this problem?

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 360;

var xEnnemy = 190;
var yEnnemy = 10;

var v = 4;

var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var can = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(xEnnemy, yEnnemy, 20, 20);

window.onkeydown = function direc(e) {
  //Move left
  if (e.keyCode == 37 && x > 0) {
    x -= v;
  }
  //Move up
  if (e.keyCode == 38 && y > 0) {
    y -= v;
  }
  //Move right
  if (e.keyCode == 39 && x < (width - 40)) {
    x += v;
  }

  //Move down
  if (e.keyCode == 40 && y < (height - 40)) {
    y += v;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);

}

function ennemy() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(xEnnemy, yEnnemy, 40, 40);
}
```

```css
#can {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="can" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you are doing in the: `function direc(e) {`

```
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
```

That is effectively wiping the canvas and only drawing one rectangle...

Here is what I would do

```js
var player = {x:10, y:100, v: 4}
var enemy = {x:190, y:10};

var can = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");

window.onkeydown = function direc(e) {  
  if (e.keyCode == 37 && player.x > 0) 
    player.x -= player.v; // Move left
  if (e.keyCode == 38 && player.y > 0)
    player.y -= player.v; // Move up
  if (e.keyCode == 39 && player.x < (can.width - 40)) 
    player.x += player.v; // Move right
  if (e.keyCode == 40 && player.y < (can.height - 40))
    player.y += player.v; // Move down
  
  draw()
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
  ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 40, 40);

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y  , 20, 20);
}

draw()
```

```css
#can {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="160"></canvas>
```

I consolidated all the drawing in one location `function draw()` any time we need to draw we can call that, at the moment you only have one event: `onkeydown` but as your game gets more complex very likely you will have more and they all will require drawing, we just call the same function.

Also I introduced objects `player = {x:10, y:100, v: 4}` that keep all the properties of the player in one object, that makes the code easier to read

Comment: @SShane let me know if you have any question ... and do not forget to upvote and mark the answer you consider correct

Answer (score 2):

Using `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);` clears the entire scene so you need to redraw **everything**.

You probably want to define a `drawPlayer` function similar to `ennemy` like:

```
function drawPlayer(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
}
```

Then, after updating the game state you'd call:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
drawPlayer();
ennemy();
```

This will update the canvas with the new positions and with the appropriate colors.